# HTML5 database site for Android, which way is best?

Tags: database, html, mobile

I am developing a web site that should work offline and should work across mobile platforms, and I wonder how to implement the local database, and the synchronization.

The site will use HTML5, so:

1) I can use the Web database, but I understand that it is no longer supported?

2) I can use the PhoneGap database, which seems to be cross platform?

Are there any other methods to do it?

Can you refer me to examples on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

**[What do you mean by Offline](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/whats-offline/)**

Writing applications for multiple operating systems and a wide range of mobile devices can be challenging. The high demand for sophisticated mobile applications requires significant hardware. One solution is to provide Web applications, because they can run cross-platform on mobile devices. You don't need to use proprietary technology (such as Objective-C with Cocoa on the iPhone); you can use common Web technology. In essence, just one version of the application is needed. The main hardware power is provided by servers. In this article, explore the use of Web development in the mobile application space with a simple example that taps into the HTML5 standard.

**[Here is the example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-offlineweb/)**